# How to crop the elements not fit to a WrapPanel

Tags: wpf, crop, wrappanel

The example of the `WrapPanel`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DestinationItemsControlStyle}"
                  DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModelKey}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Stations}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource DestinationButtonStyle}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" Style="{StaticResource DestinationTextBlockStyle}"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

If there are to many elements then all these "excessive" elements become rendered in half of their's real size. Is there a way not to render such the elements?

Am I forced to use something like `VirtualizedWrapPanel`?

I also want to notice that I can't use a scroll bar. All the "excessive" elements should be rendered on the next page which can be visited by the user's click on the button "Next".

Comment: What kind of container are you overriding the `ItemsControl` for?  The default behavior of a `WrapPanel` (placed in a grid) is to do exactly what you want; not scale the items, just don't show the extra items.  The container a control is in can change the behavior/appearance of a control.  For instance, if you have your `WrapPanel` inside a `Viewbox`, it will scale the `WrapPanel` and its contents, so that all the items in the `WrapPanel` fit on the screen.

Comment: I have updated the post. If ItemsControl resides in a Grid the behavior stays the same(((

Comment: I test ran your XAML above, and it works fine (no scaling).  The only part of your XAML that I could not duplicate is your 3 styles: `DestinationItemsControlStyle`,  `DestinationButtonStyle`, and `DestinationTextBlockStyle`.  That leads me to believe that the scaling is occuring within one of those styles.  If you can post the XAML for those styles, that might help.

Comment: Set MinWidth of Buttons to 400, MinHeight to 50 and Window's size to 1280x1024. Then add about 70 elements to the collection and you'll get the described behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1024" Width="1280">

<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl1" Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Stations}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Margin="20" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="400">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}" 
                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and the addition of 70 items in the `Stations` collection at startup, produces this result:

[image]

What does your `DestinationItemsControlStyle` look like?

For reference, this is the code-behind that runs on Startup:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     ViewModelKey vmk = new ViewModelKey();
     ItemsControl1.DataContext = vmk;
  }
}
```

and in the `ViewModelKey` class:

```
public class ViewModelKey : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  public ObservableCollection<station> Stations { get; set; }

  public ViewModelKey()
  {
     Stations = new ObservableCollection<station>();
     for (int i = 1; i < 70; i++)
     {
        Stations.Add(new station("This is station " + i.ToString()));
     }
  }

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
  {
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
     {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
  }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: And your example shows that a part of buttons in the third column is cropped. This is because buttons width exceeds the width of the window. In this case I don't want the third column even to be  rendered.

Comment: Ok, your question makes sense now.  I couldn't figure out how you were getting the buttons to be scaled (shrunk), which is what  'rendered at half their real size' means.

Comment: That type of control behavior will require a fairly advanced custom control.  Lots of code required in order to dynamically calculate how many items can fit on each page and update the number of items on each page and the number of pages in the control.  Especially if it has to update when the window resizes.

Comment: Fortunately, I always have the maximized window.